# How to run Kubectl command from Bastion Host on Private EKS clsuter

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks

I have setup a `EKS` Cluster on in a `VPC (VPC-1)` with 2 `private subnets` and no public internet access. I have created another `VPC (VPC-2)` with a `public subnet` and launched a `Bastion` host in this VPC. Created `VPC peering` between VPC-1 and VPC-2. I have ssh'ed into the Bastion host and tried to connect to the Private EKS cluster and was unsuccessful. What could be missing here? I want to run kubectl commands on this cluster.

When I try to connect to the run kubbectl,

```
kubectl get pods
```

I see the below.

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.1.125:443: i/o timeout
```

Since the VPC's are peered, the private subnets IP's should be advertised on the other VPC right?

Comment: Is it private eks cluster or just private subnets? Did you add kube config in your bastion? How about vpc endpoints? Can you do a **curl -v** to cluster endpoint? Why not create public subnets in the same VPC and test it first?

Comment: @FranxiHidro The timeouts was because kube config was not configured correctly. Now working fine.

Comment: @ZZzzZZzz can you please tell me what was the issue in kube config, i am facing the same issue

Comment: hi @ZZzzZZzz, can you share what is the correct configuration for your kubectl?